# How to get /mnt/ emmc storage info?

Tags: android, storage

I'm using:

```
 File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
    long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
    return totalBlocks * blockSize;
```

to get total internal device memory.

problem is it doesn't count the emmc storage. any suggestions on how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs("/mnt/emmc");
long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
long availableBlocks = (long)stat.getBlockCount()
return availableBlocks * blockSize;
```

This will give you the total size of the emmc

Answer (score 1):

do you have busybox installed .. then df command in the terminal shows information about all devices mounted

Comment: as far as I understand you can't invoke busybox programatically which is in this case not a suitable solution. Still, I thank you for the time and thought.